# Does the Rust compiler automatically remove unnecessary intermediate variables?

Tags: performance, variables, optimization, rust, compiler-construction

In some languages, I'm told that the compiler will perform optimizations that remove unnecessary "intermediate" local variables to improve execution efficiency.

Does somebody know if Rust does this as well? For example, consider the following code snippets:

```
fn main() {
    // has four local variables
    let x = 3;
    let y = 5;
    let temp_result = x + y;
    let final_result = temp_result * 40;
    println!("The final result is: {}", final_result);
}
```

Compare to the implementation below, which appears to have zero explicitly created local variables

```
fn main() {
    // has no explicitly created local variables
    println!("The final result is: {}", (3+5) * 40);
}
```

**Would these generate identical machine code?**

Said differently, does the compiler "realize" that the four local variables in the first implementation are provably equivalent, given the hard-coded integer inputs, to the second implementation?

Comment: There's never a guarantee about optimizations, but a trivial case like this one is very easy to optimize, so it comes as close to a guarantee as possible. I suggest you simply look at the machine code and compare it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Sven, I didn't realize I could see the ASM so easily from the playground to compare the compiler output. Cormac's answer made this clear through his Playground link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=bd25c431ce0977b19af5d70e6cb12677) to a test version. Looking at the assembly generated in release mode:

```
playground::main:
    pushq   %r15
    pushq   %r14
    pushq   %r12
    pushq   %rbx
    subq    $72, %rsp
    ####################### f1() here
    movl    $320, 4(%rsp) # whole function optimized to static value of 320
    #######################
    leaq    4(%rsp), %r14
    movq    %r14, 8(%rsp)
    movq    core::fmt::num::imp::<impl core::fmt::Display for i32>::fmt@GOTPCREL(%rip), %r15
    movq    %r15, 16(%rsp)
    leaq    .L__unnamed_2(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, 24(%rsp)
    movq    $2, 32(%rsp)
    movq    $0, 40(%rsp)
    leaq    8(%rsp), %rbx
    movq    %rbx, 56(%rsp)
    movq    $1, 64(%rsp)
    movq    std::io::stdio::_print@GOTPCREL(%rip), %r12
    leaq    24(%rsp), %rdi
    callq   *%r12
    ####################### f2() here
    movl    $320, 4(%rsp) # same as with f1()
    #######################
    movq    %r14, 8(%rsp)
    movq    %r15, 16(%rsp)
    leaq    .L__unnamed_3(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, 24(%rsp)
    movq    $2, 32(%rsp)
    movq    $0, 40(%rsp)
    movq    %rbx, 56(%rsp)
    movq    $1, 64(%rsp)
    leaq    24(%rsp), %rdi
    callq   *%r12
    addq    $72, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %r12
    popq    %r14
    popq    %r15
    retq
```

Because the return values are known statically in your example, the functions don't even appear in the compiled code. You actually get the same thing even if you define the functions like this:

```rust
fn f1(a: i32, b: i32, c:i32) -> i32 {
    let x = a;
    let y = b;
    let temp_result = x + y;
    let final_result = temp_result * c;
    final_result
}

fn f2(a: i32, b: i32, c: i32) -> i32 {
    (a + b) * c
}

pub fn main() {
    println!("f1() = {}", f1(3, 5, 40));
    println!("f2() = {}", f2(3, 5, 40));
}
```

What happens if the parameters aren't known at compile time? [Here's another playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=244996b8f75d067a07c02dfaf18c7a59), this time with the values calculated randomly and with both functions tagged `#[inline(never)]`:

```
playground::f1:
    leal    (%rdi,%rsi), %eax
    imull   %edx, %eax
    retq

playground::main:
    # rng initialization...

.LBB7_20:
    movl    8(%rbp,%rax,4), %ebx
    addq    $1, %rax
    movq    %rax, (%rbp)
    movl    %r15d, %edi
    movl    %r12d, %esi
    movl    %ebx, %edx
    ######################## f1() called here
    callq   playground::f1 #
    ########################
    movl    %eax, 4(%rsp)
    leaq    4(%rsp), %rax
    movq    %rax, 8(%rsp)
    movq    core::fmt::num::imp::<impl core::fmt::Display for i32>::fmt@GOTPCREL(%rip), %r13
    movq    %r13, 16(%rsp)
    leaq    .L__unnamed_3(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, 24(%rsp)
    movq    $2, 32(%rsp)
    movq    $0, 40(%rsp)
    leaq    8(%rsp), %rbp
    movq    %rbp, 56(%rsp)
    movq    $1, 64(%rsp)
    movq    std::io::stdio::_print@GOTPCREL(%rip), %r14
    leaq    24(%rsp), %rdi
    callq   *%r14
    movl    %r15d, %edi
    movl    %r12d, %esi
    movl    %ebx, %edx
    ######################## and again here!
    callq   playground::f1 #
    ########################
    # ...
    retq
```

The compiler has actually recognized that the functions are identical and collapsed them into a single definition.